# prolog store a list in a variable

Tags: prolog

```
prod([[vin(110 "Mercurey", 1978, 13), vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12)],
      [viticulteur("Nicolas","Pouilly","Bourgogne"),
       viticulteur("Martin","Bordaux","Bordelais")]], R)
```

This predicate is returning a list:

```
R = [[vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")]]
```

I want to store this list "R" in a variable on my program. How can I do that? What I want to do is just like:

```
list = [1, 2, 3] (in Python)

vin6(prod([[vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), vin(120, "Macon", 1977 , 12)],
           [viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne"),
            viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")]], R))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
R = [[vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")]]
```

is valid Prolog; it holds when `R` unifies with that list. e.g.

```
test(X) :-
    R = [[vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")], 
     [vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")]],
    nth1(1, R, X).
```

Then:

```
?- test(X).
[vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")]
```

---

I think it might be more normal to do almost what Enigmativity suggests, but rather using the database for the individual entries not for the list, like this:

```
wine(vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")).
wine(vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")). 
wine(vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Nicolas", "Pouilly", "Bourgogne")). 
wine(vin(120, "Macon", 1977, 12), viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais")).

test(Second) :-
    findall((Vin, Viti), wine(Vin, Viti), R),
    nth1(2, R, Second).
```

Then:

```
?- test(Second).
Second = (vin(110, "Mercurey", 1978, 13),viticulteur("Martin", "Bordaux", "Bordelais"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a fact in your program.

```
list([1, 2, 3]).
```

Now you can unify a variable in any predicate at any time with `list(Xs)`.